# eval_in_page javascript execution works in firefox but not in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, html, perl, phantomjs, mechanize

I'm trying to automate a javascript heavy page in Perl using `Mechanize::PhantomJS`. There is some javascript that is executed on the page after the user clicks either okay or cancel in a confirm alert. Since I don't know how to press okay, I'm executing the javascript directly. The **problem** is that the following script works fine when using firefox (here I use `Mechanize::Firefox`) but doesn't produce any result when using `Mechanize::PhantomJS`

```
$mech->eval_in_page(<<'JS');
   closeChildWindows();
   commandInProgress = true;
   document.dataForm.target="_self";
   document.dataForm.method='post';
   document.dataForm.action="ReviewApptAction";  
   document.dataForm.submit();
JS
```

In PhantomJS, the script goes through these lines without producing any error but doesn't execute anything on the page, meaning I don't get any result such as submitting the form at the end. Does anyone know what's going on here?

I want to use `Mechanize::PhantomJS` because it allows me to run multiple instances of the script concurrently, unlike firefox.

Let me be more clear on this: I have to press a button which has an onclick javascript attached to it:

```
<a href="javascript:bookAppointment()" onmouseover="window.status='Next Screen';return true" onmouseout="window.status='';return true">
            <img src="../images/include/buttonnext.gif" width="61" height="16" border="0" alt="Next Screen"></a>
```

The function that this button calls is this:

```
function bookAppointment()
{
    if ( confirm("Book this appointment?") )
    {
         if ( !commandInProgress) {
                closeChildWindows();
                commandInProgress = true;
                document.dataForm.target="_self";
                document.dataForm.method='post';
                document.dataForm.action="ReviewApptAction";  
                document.dataForm.submit();
         }
         else {
              alert("Request has been submitted but not yet processed by the server.  Please press OK and wait for response...");
         }
    }
    return;
```

}

First, I used `$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' [ => 1 ])` to click okay in confirm dialog but that didn't work. So, I simply issued the commands that follow the okay click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS#mech-confirm-Really-do-this-1):

> **`$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' [ => 1 ])`**
>
> Records a confirmation (which is "1" or "ok" by default) [...]

As Artjom B. says in the comments, the `[ => 1 ]` indicates that a second argument is optional and that the default value is 1. If you want to pass the second argument, you have to remove the brackets, since the following is invalid Perl code and will cause a syntax error:

```
$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' [ => 1 ]);
```

```
syntax error at ./foo line 42, near "'Really do this?' ["
Execution of ./foo aborted due to compilation errors.
```

To hit "ok", do:

```
$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' => 1);
```

or since 1 is the default, simply:

```
$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' );
```

If you want to cancel the dialog, use:

```
$mech->confirm( 'Really do this?' => 0 );
```

Comment: Finally someone who follows SO etiquette (posting as CW). I have never used Perl, so I'm not comfortable writing up an answer based on an assumption.

Comment: Well, you nailed the problem and were correct in telling the OP to write an answer. I'm using `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS` right now so I figured it'd be faster to just throw together an answer instead of waiting for the OP.